# Scroll effect Glitch, hacks, bounces in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, safari, visual-glitch

So I have a site with slides, and I need to fake fixed position, using jQuery for this. It works perfect in chrome and Firefox but glitches (jumping up to the top before finding right position) in Safari. Is there a better way to do this?

JS:

```
function fakeFixed(){
        $fakeFixed = $('.fake-fixed');
        $window = $(window);
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            $fakeFixed.each(function(){
                $this = $(this);

                $this.css('margin-top', $window.scrollTop() - $this.parent().position().top);
                        console.log();
                }

            });
    } //cLose fakeFixed

    fakeFixed();
```

Comment: I remember there is a bug on Safari where the scroll event does fire resize events every time. So if you have event listeners for resizing, those might cause problems.

Comment: Ok, you know of a workaround? Or is it a no-go?

Comment: It really depends on the code your resize listeners execute, there is no generic workaround I know of. Maybe store the page width and only execute the resize-depending code if the page width changed?